# why there is no endpoint type?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I design an api as the official context,when I imlement the managed api ,there is no endpoint type as the official context. why ? like the following image

[image: why there is no endpoint type ?]

Comment: Do you see any errors in logs? Please try in a private browser window as well.

Comment: It is ok, I think this elements is generating in api manager. Next time go in again, It appears.